# Yammer-ANT : How to send notification on yammer using ANT?

Tags: java, ant, yammer

I want to send notification on yammer using ANT, How to ?

We are doing build process in that when Our build succeed. Then we want to send notification (feed) to Our members present in Group on yammer. So all members will know that "Build process successfully Done".

Is there any way to send notification(feed) on yammer only ?

Please do the needful.

Hope for the best co-operation from your side.

Comment: @martin Thanks for Adding "Yammer" tag to my Question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to try is to use Yammer's email integration, and have ant send an email to a yammer email account, which should be posted to yammer.

Links to some details-
[Posting to Yammer via email](https://www.yammer.com/company/email)

[sending email from ant](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/trunk/docs/manual/listeners.html#MailLogger)

It'll take you some time to put these together, but it should work.

Comment: ) Thanks for your help. :) 2nd way work for me i.e sending email from ant. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), there is a [Yammer plugin for it](http://code.google.com/p/hudson-yammer/).

Comment: can you provide more documentation on this. Step by step documentation help alothel a lot